# Flash AS3:Multiple function in one key?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Etc: if I press "space" key, inventory opens.But if I press "space" again, inventory should close.What should I use for this kind of thing?I can open it, but cant close.Thanks, sorry for bad english.(P.S: Im using flashdevelop+flixel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible.

```
var isInventOpen:Boolean = false;
function openCloseInvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE && isInventOpen == false)
    {
         //Open Inventory
         isInventOpen = true;
    }

    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE && isInventOpen == true)
    {
         //Close Inventory
         isInventOpen = false;
    }
}
```

More info on KeyCodes can be found here: [KeyCodes](http://www.dakmm.com/?p=272), if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You should give yourself a boolean, like so:

```
var menuOpen:Boolean = false;
function yourEventHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (menuOpen) {
        menuOpen = false;
        //close your menu here
    } else {
        menuOpen = true;
        //open menu here
    }
}
```